# C# - how to check char for pipe symbol?

Tags: c#, string, char

I have a file that I am generating, which follows the following format:

=

Sometimes the second string will be empty, so I have to generate a value based on the first string. For example, if the first string is "StackOverflow", I am generating the second value as "Stack Overflow".

The problem is that sometimes the first value will have a pipe character (a remnant of an older platform), i.e. "18|2". I want to not add a space before or after the pipe symbol. I have a loop that checks each character in the first string value (from the format above). I want to check if the previous character is a pipe, and ignore that case. The problem is, I'm not sure how to check for the pipe "|" character.

**EDIT** Here's the code as it is now:

```
private string createNewTitleFromFieldId(string fieldId) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldId))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    string newTitleValue = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < fieldId.Length; i++) {
        char currentChar = fieldId[i];
        char previousChar = i == 0 ? fieldId[i] : fieldId[i - 1];

        // Only perform checks if the current character is not the first character in the string.
        if (i != 0) {

            // If the current character is upper-case, and preceded by a lower-case character, append a preceding space.
            if (char.IsUpper(currentChar) && !char.IsUpper(previousChar))
                newTitleValue += string.Format(" {0}", currentChar);

            // If the current character is a number, but is not preceded by a number.
            else if (char.IsNumber(currentChar) && !char.IsNumber(previousChar)) 
                newTitleValue += string.Format(" {0}", currentChar);

            // If the character is a number, but preceded by a pipe "|" character.
            else if (char.IsNumber(currentChar) && char.Equals(previousChar, '|')) 
                newTitleValue += currentChar;

            // Add the current character to the Title if it does not match the above criteria.
            else newTitleValue += currentChar;
        }

        // Add the current character if the index is 0, otherwise we lose the first character.
        else newTitleValue += currentChar;
    }

    return newTitleValue;
}
```

Examples of desired input/output:

in: "StackOverFlow" out: "Stack Over Flow"

in: "Stack1Over11Flow111" out: "Stack 1 Over 11 Flow 111"

in: "Stack|1OverFlow|11" out: "Stack|1 Over Flow|11"

Comment: As you didn´t provide the code how you turn `"StackOverflow"` into "`Stack Overflow"` it´s hard to guess how you could do that by ignoring the pipe. What would be the desired outcome for `"Stack|Overflow"`?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm simply adding spaces into the first string if there is an upper-case letter after a lower-case letter, or a number that is not preceded by another number. Example input/output would be:

in: "18|2"  out: "18|2"
in: "StackOverFlow" out: "Stack Over Flow"
in: "Stack1OverFlow22" out "Stack 1 Over Flow 22"

I've got everything working except for the first example with pipe characters. My code is adding a space after the pipe character.

Comment: Its hard to see why your code is not working as you have not included it all. If you are checking for upper case characters & numbers there should be no need to check for the pipe.

Comment: I've updated the original post with my full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have you else if blocks in the wrong order.

You are checking that the previous character is not a number before checking that is not a pipe:

Swap the two else blocks rounds and the input 18|2 outputs 18|2

```
private string createNewTitleFromFieldId(string fieldId) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldId))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    string newTitleValue = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < fieldId.Length; i++) {
        char currentChar = fieldId[i];
        char previousChar = i == 0 ? fieldId[i] : fieldId[i - 1];

        // Only perform checks if the current character is not the first character in the string.
        if (i != 0) {

            // If the current character is upper-case, and preceded by a lower-case character, append a preceding space.
            if (char.IsUpper(currentChar) && !char.IsUpper(previousChar)) 
            {
                    newTitleValue += string.Format(" {0}", currentChar);
            }
            // If the character is a number, but preceded by a pipe "|" character.
            else if (char.IsNumber(currentChar) && char.Equals(previousChar, '|')) {
                    newTitleValue += currentChar;
            }

            // If the current character is a number, but is not preceded by a number.
            else if (char.IsNumber(currentChar) && !char.IsNumber(previousChar)) {
                    newTitleValue += string.Format(" {0}", currentChar);
            }

            // Add the current character to the Title if it does not match the above criteria.
            else newTitleValue += currentChar;
        }

            // Add the current character if the index is 0, otherwise we lose the first character.
            else newTitleValue += currentChar;
        }

        return newTitleValue;
    }
```

You can then merge the two statements together

```
// If the current character is upper-case, and preceded by a lower-case character, append a preceding space.
if (char.IsUpper(currentChar) && !char.IsUpper(previousChar))
{
    newTitleValue += string.Format(" {0}", currentChar);
}
// If the current character is a number, but is not preceded by a number or pipe.
else if (char.IsNumber(currentChar) && !char.IsNumber(previousChar) && !char.Equals(previousChar, '|'))
{
    newTitleValue += string.Format(" {0}", currentChar);
}
// Add the current character to the Title if it does not match the above criteria.
else newTitleValue += currentChar;
```

Comment: This was the problem. The first issue is the first if statement - it's catching anything that's not an uppercase letter, so the if statements further down weren't being checked. I rearranged/corrected the code and it's all working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For checking for a pipe character, you can simply use

```
if (currentChar == '|')
```

Make sure that you use the single quote instead of double quote to designate that you are working with a character.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of looking for a pipe symbol you can try adding spaces if

1. before digit if previous charater is a letter
2. before capital ltter if previous charater is a letter or digit

Implementation

```
private static string Builder(string source) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    return source;

  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i) {
    char current = source[i];

    if (i > 0) {
      char prior = source[i - 1];

      if (char.IsLetter(prior) && char.IsDigit(current) ||
          char.IsLetterOrDigit(prior) && char.IsUpper(current))
        result.Append(' ');
    }

    result.Append(current);
  }

  return result.ToString();
}
```

Test

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "StackOverFlow",
    "Stack1Over11Flow111",
    "Stack|1OverFlow|11",
  };

  foreach (var item in tests) {
    Console.WriteLine(Builder(item));
  }
```

Outcome:

```
Stack Over Flow
Stack 1 Over 11 Flow 111
Stack|1 Over Flow|11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if the string contains a pipe by using [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx)

This will return the index of the character if found, or -1 if it is not.

```
int pipePos = s.IndexOf('|');
if(pipePos != -1) {
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if all you want to do is add a space before every pipe symbol why do you need a loop?

```
        string s = "test|test";
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        s = s.Replace("|", " |");
        MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Comment: I need a loop because I'm doing other checks on the input string, not just for pipe characters.

Comment: you didn't say that, purhaps you should try to be more clear.                         "I want to not add a space before or after the pipe symbol. I have a loop that checks each character in the first string value (from the format above). I want to check if the previous character is a pipe, and ignore that case."